# Solve PnP or Estimate Pose Single Markers: which is better?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco, pose

I need a program to estimate the pose of an `ArUco` marker, and, as far as I know, I can code it with two different functions: `cv2.solvePnp()` or `cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarker(`). Which one is better? I read about them, and it seems easier to use `cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarker()`, but is it as accurate as `cv2.solvePnP()`?
Thanks

I am a graduating student, and I need this information because I am doing a research with a teacher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**estimatePoseSingleMarkers** no longer exists as of *version 4.7*. Here, I replaced the function for you using SolvePnP:

```
def my_estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, marker_size, mtx, distortion):
    '''
    This will estimate the rvec and tvec for each of the marker corners detected by:
       corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = detector.detectMarkers(image)
    corners - is an array of detected corners for each detected marker in the image
    marker_size - is the size of the detected markers
    mtx - is the camera matrix
    distortion - is the camera distortion matrix
    RETURN list of rvecs, tvecs, and trash (so that it corresponds to the old estimatePoseSingleMarkers())
    '''
    marker_points = np.array([[-marker_size / 2, marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [marker_size / 2, marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [marker_size / 2, -marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [-marker_size / 2, -marker_size / 2, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    trash = []
    rvecs = []
    tvecs = []
    
    for c in corners:
        nada, R, t = cv2.solvePnP(marker_points, c, mtx, distortion, False, cv2.SOLVEPNP_IPPE_SQUARE)
        rvecs.append(R)
        tvecs.append(t)
        trash.append(nada)
    return rvecs, tvecs, trash
```

Comment: I'm having trouble to use the output of this replacement function. I'm getting (with a 4.5 OpenCV):

OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:605: error: (-5:Bad argument) Rotation must be represented by 1x3 or 3x1 floating-point rotation vector, or 3x3 rotation matrix in function 'cvProjectPoints2Internal'

The output structure of the arrays is different, compared to the output of estimatePoseSingleMarkers.

Comment: Use 

"return np.array([rvecs]), np.array([tvecs]), trash"

when you return. To get exact match.