# how to estimate pose of single marker in opencv-python 4.8.0?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

As shown in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964527/attributeerror-module-cv2-aruco-has-no-attribute-dictionary-get) There are API change for aruco package.
I managed to detect the markers and  drawDetectedMarkers by following accepted answer but I can't find 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers' in both cv2.aruco and  cv2.aruco.detector attributes.
still got error message

`module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers'`

or

`'cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector' object has no attribute 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers'`

Comment: use `solvePnP()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Christoph Rackwitz comment as i searching for solvePnP with aruco tag, I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75871586/8452469)

**estimatePoseSingleMarkers** no longer exists as of *version 4.7*. Here, I replaced the function for you using SolvePnP:

```
def my_estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, marker_size, mtx, distortion):
    '''
    This will estimate the rvec and tvec for each of the marker corners detected by:
       corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = detector.detectMarkers(image)
    corners - is an array of detected corners for each detected marker in the image
    marker_size - is the size of the detected markers
    mtx - is the camera matrix
    distortion - is the camera distortion matrix
    RETURN list of rvecs, tvecs, and trash (so that it corresponds to the old estimatePoseSingleMarkers())
    '''
    marker_points = np.array([[-marker_size / 2, marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [marker_size / 2, marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [marker_size / 2, -marker_size / 2, 0],
                              [-marker_size / 2, -marker_size / 2, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    trash = []
    rvecs = []
    tvecs = []
    for c in corners:
        nada, R, t = cv2.solvePnP(marker_points, c, mtx, distortion, False, cv2.SOLVEPNP_IPPE_SQUARE)
        rvecs.append(R)
        tvecs.append(t)
        trash.append(nada)
    return rvecs, tvecs, trash
```

if anyone have this problem,I've wrote example script in my github.
https://github.com/Menginventor/aruco_example_cv_4.8.0

Comment: almost. you don't need `i`, remove it. you never use `c`. use it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I just copy/paste from original post, I just see it now, thank.